# Row click datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery

I am using jquery datatables plugin. The row click functionality is working fine on the first page, when I go to any of the next pages, the row click doesn't work with `.on("click", function() { ....});`

I tried to replace `.on()` with `.live()` and seems to work fine. My concern is `.live()` has been deprecated since jquery 1.7. Is it a bug with the `.on()` or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delegate the event using `on` method, you should code:

```
$(document).on("click", "selector", function() { ....});
```

or:

```
$('staticParent').on("click", "dynamicDescendant", function() { ....});
```

Comment: Isn't the selector optional? `If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Liam For regular event handling, yes, but for event delegation, no.

Comment: I think I see the issue so the OP is doing `$(selector).on(....);` and your saying it should be `$(document).on('click', selector....);` :)